# How to select a value from a table in R

Tags: r

I have the following data, called fit.2.sim:

```
An object of class "sim"
Slot "coef":
fit.2.sim

       [,1]        [,2]
 [1,] -1.806363 5.148728
 [2,] -3.599123 5.183769
 [3,]  4.192562 4.855095
 [4,]  2.658218 4.967007
 [5,] -2.304084 5.220325
 [6,] -1.010406 5.071663
 [7,]  2.601671 5.129750
 [8,]  5.977764 4.757826
 [9,]  3.873432 4.932319
[10,]  1.281331 5.138091

Slot "sigma":
 [1]  8.285497 10.659971  9.568340  8.649106  8.611894  9.041444  8.316859  7.990499  8.985450
[10]  7.947142
```

The command I have been using, to no avail unfortunately is:

```
fit.2.sim$coef[i,j]
```

i,j being the respective rows and columns. The error I get is:

> "Error in fit.2.sim$coef : $ operator not defined for this S4 class"

Could you please tell me if there is another way to make this work?

Comment: I believe S4 classes use `@` to access slots, not `$`.

Comment: @joran You are right, thank you! Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can mark as it as the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S4 classes use `@` not `$` to access slots, so you probably wanted

```
fit.t.sim@coef[i,j]
```